# Nginx exiting with Error code after https config

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, webserver

I ran through this manual: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-ssl-on-nginx/

I'm Working on Ubuntu 18.04 with an nginx webserver
At the end I tried to restart nginx but the server was down.

I deleted all the files I created during the process and got the following error message:

```
2021/03/12 12:20:08 [emerg] 1767#1767: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.example.com" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

The file still exists in `/etc/nginx/sites-enables/www.example.com`, but is empty.

If I need to provide more information just ask.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the path to config file:

> The file still exists in /etc/nginx/sites-enables/www.example.com, but
> is empty.

But it should exists following the path mentioned in the nginx config:

> open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.example.com" failed (2: No such
> file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62

You can fix this moving the config from sites-enables/www.example.com to sites-enabled/www.example.com.
Also before you start nginx after altering config files it's best to check the configs using nginx -t command (or nginx -t -c /path/to/config).

Answer (score 1):

In your config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf on line 62, you are including another config file. There is probably something like:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

This line includes all config files in **/etc/nginx/site-enabled/** directory.

Look there, and you will find file *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*. This file is symbolic link referring to real file located at */etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com*

But real file most likely does not exists so it cannot be open by nginx process. Remove symlink referring to non existent file and you should be fine:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.example.com
```

Now start nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove these two files:

rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.example.com

Thanks for your help!

Clay